# Undefined value when subscribing to subject using Event Bus Implementation

Tags: angular

I created an `EventBusService` and `EventData`

```
export class EventData {
    public eventName: string;
    public event: any;

    constructor(eventName: string, event: any) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.event = event;
    }
}


@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class EventBusService {
    private subject = new Subject();

    public emit(event: EventData) {
        this.subject.next(event);
    }

    public on(eventName: string, action: any): Subscription {
        return this.subject.pipe(
            filter( (e: EventData) => e.eventName === eventName),
            map( (e: EventData) => e['value'])).subscribe(action);

    }
}
```

This is how I emitted the event

`this.eventBusService.emit(new EventData('SelectDefaultList', list));`

The values has been emitted but I always get the `undefined` value when subscribing/listening to the `EventBusService`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.eventBusService.on('SelectDefaultList', (list: List) => {
        console.log('hello' + list);
    });
}
```

The two components are under one module which I declared the `EventBusService` as provider.

Thank you~

Comment: Define your subject like that  private subject Subject<EventData> = new Subject();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **EventData** has no `value` property, so here returns undefined - `(e: EventData) => e['value'])`.

Also you can simplify its class by moving `public` to constructor properties:

```
export class EventData {
  constructor(public eventName: string, public event: any) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have named my variable as `value` and not `event`. Thanks, dev!